# how to use opengl for nana c++ library?

Tags: opengl, nana

I am playing on nana library for gui.

I also have to use opengl, But there is one example for opengl, which is for windows.  [Link](http://%20https://sourceforge.net/p/nanapro/blog/2015/01/tour-of-nana-10/)

I am using ubuntu linux. above example call `reinterpret_cast<HWND>`(`fm.native_handle()`);

I finally have found it.

The root window attaches to the OS/Windowing system native window, native_handle returns the handle of native window.
In a certain system, the native_window_type can be converted into system native handle type.

```
auto reinterpret_cast<HWND>(root_widget.native_handle()); //Windows
auto reinterpret_cast<Window>(root_widget.native_handle()); //Linux/X11
```

I may get hint between *HWND*, Window.

If I use **Window(X11)**, can I implement to `opengl` on `nana` library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an app that uses OpenGL you need, very very simplified, at least four things:

- A pixel format, describing colors-size, Z-buffer size, multisampling,
  etc. In Windows you need `wglChoosePixelFormatARB`. In Linux,
  `glXChooseFBConfig`.
- A context. In Windows
  `wglCreateContextAttribsARB` requires a `HDC` and in Linux `glXCreateContextAttribsARB` a
  `Display`, which is not the same as a window.
- How to set the context as current.
- How to "swap  buffers".

You can learn more [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.1_The_First_Triangle_(C%2B%2B/Win)) and [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.0_Context_Creation_(GLX)).

If you find documentation on these matters for OpenGL version < 3.2, please don't use it. Stick to "modern" OpenGL.

The issue with `nana` is that the example you linked seems to work well for Windows (but old OGL). Nothing is told about Linux. I think you should dig into the source code of `nana` searching for what it returns on `native_handle()`. Better you prefer to ask in its forum.

The above functions I showed are not directly available, you must query their function pointers.

And many of modern OGL functions require also to retrieve their function pointers. See [the wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions#Windows_2)